# How to open a fragment on searchView menu item in action bar click in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I have implemented expanded searchView in my actionBar. So now when I click on it, it opens keyboard and I can write in the search bar itself. But I want to open a fragment when I click on that menu item, i.e, I don't want to write in searchView but to open a separate fragment.

I have tried onClickListener and onSearchClickListener but it's not working. 
Any solution?

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                SearchView searchView = new SearchView(mActivity.actionBar.getThemedContext());
                searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(mActivity.getComponentName()));
                searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
                searchView.setQueryHint(svo.getKeyword());
                searchView.setMaxWidth(500);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setActionView(searchView);
                searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putSerializable(URLConfig.SEARCH_VO_KEY, svo);
                        BaseFragment fragment = new SearchFormFrg();
                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        mActivity.singleInstanceReplaceFragment(fragment);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: How are you adding searchview in the menu item?

Comment: This is menu.xml code:
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_stat_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        />
And i have added searchview to this item which can be seen in the original code provided in question.

Comment: just override onOptionsItemSelected() method and get the click listener over there and perform desired action